# How to create hyperlink to a filter on other sheet using Apache poi in Java?

Tags: java, excel, hyperlink, apache-poi

I want to create a hyperlink from a field 'Name' on Sheet1 (Summary) to the AutoFilter on column 'Name' on Sheet2 (Details), in order to display the details of that particular name only on the Sheet2.

I have imported :

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Hyperlink;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
```

Hyperlink to filter on other sheet.

I have done this using VB macro, but want to implement this using Java POI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported with JAVA POI - Till what I found..

Comment: Have you found any other library to achieve same functionality?

Comment: This was 5 years back, I hope Java POI does support it by now.

Answer (score 1):

I had troubles with Hyperlinks some time ago, and the quickest way to do that (I was in a hurry too!) is the following:

```
row.createCell(cellIdx, HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA).setCellFormula(String.format("HYPERLINK(%s; \"%s\")", sheetAndCellLocation, friendlyText));
```

Comment: How does it relates to the filter ?

Comment: I thought your root problem was related to the use of Hyperlinks.

Have you considered using Excel's procv/proch formulas?

Answer (score 1):

To insert hyperlink into cell in Excel sheet using Apache POI we need CreationHelper, we need to get CreationHelper from WorkBook (like XSSFWorkBook).
Code snippet:

```
CreationHelper creationHelper = getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();
Hyperlink link = creationHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL);
link.setAddress("www.google.com");
```

There are other types of HyperLink available in Apache POI one of them is LINK_URL.
also we can apply style to hyperlink created by default it will be blue and underlined.

```
XSSFCellStyle hLinkStyle = getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
Font hLinkFont = getWorkbook().createFont();
hLinkFont.setFontName("Ariel");
hLinkFont.setUnderline(Font.U_SINGLE);
hLinkFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex() );
hLinkStyle.setFont(hLinkFont);
```