# Setting ScreenTip in Excel Hyperlinks using Apache-POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using POI 3.8 to create Excel sheets using Java

I have created hyperlinks successfully using the method explained by Prashant Jadhav in  [How to Create Hyperlink to a filter on other sheet using Apache poi in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728945/how-to-create-hyperlink-to-a-filter-on-other-sheet-using-apache-poi-in-java)

However I would like to set the ScreenTip as well

I tried

```
linkPrint.setLabel("Print");
```

but to no avail.

Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: POI 1.8, are you serious? That was never officially released, and would date from about 8 years ago! Is there a reason why you're not using a release from this decade?

Comment: Thank you Gagravarr. I corrected the typo. I meant 3.8 not 1.8!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not possible for the current implementation for the HyperLink in Apache POI to include a tooltip. Check the HyperLink interface. It only has 4 properties :

- The link address.
- The link label.
- The link type which is a read-only property.

http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/common/usermodel/Hyperlink.html#getType%28%29